# If the integrals of two function are equal then the functions are equal almost everywhere. true or false?

Tags: analysis

Actually I know that if the integral of a non negative function is equal to zero then that function is equal to zero almost everywhere. Can I use that to prove or is there a counterexample for my above problem? Note by integral I mean Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Lebes**g**ue, incidentally. (For a counter-example, consider e.g. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\pi]}(x)dx$.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} \ dx = \int_0^1 x \ dx$$